# Can the backend service be private when using firebase auth with Google API gateway?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I am trying to run a cloud run/ cloud functions service through google API gateway. I am using firebase authentication on the gateway as security.

Initially, I had my services private and was getting 403. It gave me 200 once I added allUsers with Cloud Run Invoker to the permissions to the service I am trying to invoke. So I am a bit confused here. Part of the reason I am using API gateway with firebase auth is to protect it against unauthorised calls. And for firebase auth to work, I had to add allUsers, making it public. My understanding was that the API gateway alone would be public while all the backend services that it invokes would be private. In this case, the service can be directly invoked by anyone, rendering the security at the API Gateway useless. How can I setup the backend to private and only respond to authenticated calls through API gateway ?

Comment: Hi @vzurd could you please give it a try checking this similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006794/api-gateway-for-microservices-with-google-cloud-functions)? It has some advice on how to use Cloud Endpoints to achieve your goal and some other alternatives, to have GCF private and only your API public.